# How to apply styles in the React app when using the "style-src 'self' "CSP policy?

Tags: css, reactjs, content-security-policy

I have implemented the CSP policy in my React app:

CSP policy:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self';">`

It blocked all the @import statements in my React components because, during rendering in React, it took the styles from the bundle. However, from the bundle, it provided the styles as a  tag to implement the style in the component. But the CSP policy blocked the  tag, so my styles are not implemented.

How can I implement a CSS file without using the @import statement in a React component?

My CSP policy is blocking them from being implemented.

For minimal cases, I have implemented inline CSS to apply styling. However, for larger CSS files, I won't be able to make all the styles inline. What can I do to apply styles from larger CSS files?

Comment: Are you importing google fonts?

Comment: No, I am trying to import external CSS files that I have created to apply styles to the component from the same origin.

Comment: Just use `unsafe-inline`

Comment: I can put a `unsafe-inline` against the style-src but I do want to impose this policy.

Answer (score 0):

> It blocked all the @import statements ?

Because, wepack tries to add the styles as inline.

so you must specify the allowance by adding `unsafe-inline` to the `style-src` directive

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Comment: I could include `unsafe-inline` in the `style-src` directive to allow inline styles, but I'm reluctant to adopt this approach as it undermines the security policy I want to enforce.

Comment: It is ok to use inline, because we faced several integration issues. Using this, you might have some another errors while loading scripts in production build.

Comment: I think `strict-dynamic` will help you. [Refer this](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/#:~:text=It%20is%20only%20ok%20to,CSP%20Level%202%20or%20lower.)

Comment: In Content Security Policy (CSP), the `strict-dynamic` directive is typically applied within the `script-src` directive, rather than the `style-src` directive.

Comment: If you found anything to resolve this, share us
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self';">`
with this, `@import` should work if the origin is same.

try set specific domain

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://example.com/..;">`

or try importing as link tag if it's okay

`<link href="https://css.example.com/some-file.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: If I have only one file, the `<link>` implementation is fine. However, if I have lots of files, how can I reduce the implementation process to include all the external CSS files into the React components?